# How to prevent Haml from escaping HTML when joining?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I would like to show a series of links separated by commas, so my HAML code looks something like:

```
- links = []
- links.append(link_to ...)
- if something
  - links.append(link_to ...)
= links.join(,)
```

The problem is that Haml escapes the links in the produced html:

> `&lt;a href=&quot;`

so the links are displayed:

> <a href="...">

instead of interpreted by the browser.

I understand that `html_safe` is used to prevent escaping but not how to combine it with `join`.  I am using haml 4.0.5 with haml-rails 0.5.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although each individual entry of the array is html safe, the result from `join` isn’t. The solution is just to call `html_safe` on the final result:

```
= links.join(', ').html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```rb
- links = []
- links.append(link_to(...).html_safe)
- if something
  - links.append(link_to(...).html_safe)
= links.join(,)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help.